# Active Directory with Two Domain Controllers 2008 and 2012

Tags: windows, server, windows-server-2008

We have two servers: 
1. Windows server 2008 Standard 32 bit. (Old server)
2. Windows server 2012 Data Center 64 Bit (New Server)

Presently the domain (abc.com) is on old server. 
there are two DCs now in this domain. one is Oldserver.abc.com and another is newserver.abc.com

the problem is before some days the users cannot be migrated between these two servers. it shows schema mismatch error in it. 
What should I Do?

Pls. help . 
Br, 
EDP

Answer (score 0):

When the 2012 servers were installed, did you have to run a schema update/upgrade? This should have taken care of all of that for you.

DCDIAG should give you some further information as to the health of your DCs.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731968%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396